# Find rows in a dataframe with more than 1 non-zero value in certain columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are 5 columns in my dataframe that have a code value, generally that code value is the same in all those columns or zero. I want to find rows where there is more than 1 distinct value, excluding zero.

So in the example below, I would like rows id 1 and 4

`df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4],'col_A':[1,1,1,0],'col_B':[2,1,0,2],'col_C':[3,1,0,3],'col_D':[4,1,1,4],'col_E':[5,1,1,5]})`

| id | col_A | col_B | col_C | col_D | col_E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |

I am able to get the answer I want with the following code, but it is really ugly and I am certain there is a better way to do it.

```
df['cats'] = df.loc[:,df.filter(like='col_').columns].apply(pd.unique, axis=1)
df[df['cats'].apply(lambda x:(len(x)-1) if 0 in x else len(x))>1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) the 0s by NaN, then use [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = df[df.filter(like='col_')
           .replace(0, float('nan'))
           .nunique(axis=1).gt(1)]
```

Output:

```
   id  col_A  col_B  col_C  col_D  col_E
0   1      1      2      3      4      5
3   4      0      2      3      4      5
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, which:

- Uses [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) + [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) + [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html#pandas.DataFrame.bfill) to replace the zeros with row-adjacent values.
- Then it compares all `col_X` columns with `col_A`, to check where the columns differ from `col_A`. This gives the boolean location of the wanted rows.
- The last line of code is to create `cats` column.

```
    d = df.iloc[:,1:].mask(df.eq(0)).ffill(axis=1).bfill(axis=1)
    m = ~d.eq(d.iloc[:, 1], axis=0).all(1)
    df[m].assign(cats = df.drop('id', axis=1).loc[m].apply(list, axis=1))
```

Output:

```
   id  col_A  col_B  col_C  col_D  col_E             cats
0   1      1      2      3      4      5  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
3   4      0      2      3      4      5  [0, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```